# Regular expression for getting viewstate from page using python re module

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

> |0|hiddenField|_*EVENTTARGET||0|hidden|*_EVENTARGUMENT||0|hiddenField|_*LASTFOCUS||3848|hiddenField|*_VIEWSTATE|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|0|hiddenField|

I need to get the value of __VIEWSTATE from this string which is :

> 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

I have tried couple of patterns using re module but none of them works.Could anyone help me in this?

Comment: so you have a pattern delimited by `|`. split your string by `|` and access the expected field

Comment: actually the string i have posted is much bigger than this.It has Html contents as well in top and bottom of string :(

Comment: `|` is quite a rare character anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
_VIEWSTATE\|([^|]*)
```

demo: http://rubular.com/r/JoFyUu5NsC

and with **@dbaupp**'s addition:

```
(?:^|\|)_VIEWSTATE\|([^|]*)
```

http://rubular.com/r/HmnapACGEw

Comment: You could add `(?:^|\|)` as a prefix, so it doesn't match anything that ends in `_VIEWSTATE`.

Answer (score 1):

This regex does this

```
_VIEWSTATE\|([^|"]*)
```

It will store the viewstate in group 1. The Python code to use is

```
reobj = re.compile(r"_VIEWSTATE\|([^|"]*)")
match = reobj.search(subject)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

Reading your comments I think an end delimiter of " is also possible right? You are dealing with ASP.NET viewstate maybe.